# What to do about "SCSIPressurePathManager: new active path available" errors?

Tags: mac-osx, drivers, esata

I have a DeLock-branded, Si3132-based eSATA ExpressCard in my MacBook Pro, with the `com.SiliconImage.driver.Si3132r5` driver 1.5.16 on 10.5.7.

Every now and then, it apparently decides to go nuts. All I/O to the external drive will be stalled for a few seconds, then continues, then stalls again, and so on. This has appeared a while ago, possibly with the 10.5.5 update. It appears to correspond to a system log message:

```
4/25/09 7:09:16 PM kernel SCSIPressurePathManager: new active path available, checking, loops = 0
```

And sure enough, 1) I know the driver works through the SCSI system (i.e., drives are faked as external SCSI ones, not SATA ones), and 2) [the most useful Google result I could find](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/feedback/express34_card_reports.html) has to do with ExpressCards. Other results suggest different drivers, but so far I've only found rebadged versions of [SI's 1.1.9 driver](http://www.siliconimage.com/support/searchresults.aspx?pid=32&cat=3) ([by Sonnet](http://www.sonnettech.com/support/downloads/computercards.html) and [by Rosewill](http://www.rosewill.com/products/d_814/productDetail.htm)), which exhibits the same problem. I assume this is some sort of caching bug.

One thing I have yet to try is to install 10.5.4's SCSI-related kernel extensions.

The stalling makes the card virtually useless, as performance via USB runs circles around this.

**Update:** as of 10.6.1 (10B504) / 1.1.11, this is still occurring.

Comment: Any luck with updating to 10.5.7?

Comment: No, the issue is still there in 10.5.7. Still haven't tried using 10.5.4's extensions, though.

Comment: Please read the ServerFault FAQ:

"Please note that Server Fault is not for general computer troubleshooting questions; if you paid for that desktop hardware, and it's your personal workstation, it is unlikely that your question is appropriate for Server Fault."

Answer (score 1):

Those links may help you :

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8628956

[http://www.snsforums.com/index.php?showtopic=250](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8628956)

[http://forums.applenova.com/showthread.php?s=3bbe55948d64dca96ea3ced8d1905626&t=32027](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8628956)

But after many search, there still no clear solution to the problem up to right now...

Hope it may help you but it's seems a very common problem with no known solution...

Comment: That third link is actually a post of mine ;) Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading your driver isn't working, you could try downgrading it instead. The vendors website has older versions available:

http://www.siliconimage.com/support/searchresults.aspx?pid=32&cat=3

Comment: I should have clarified — 1.1.9 *is* a downgrade from 1.5.16, which I typically use. 1.1.9 also causes an occasional kernel panic fixed in 1.5.16.